# ">" symbol is showing as "&gt;" when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I would like to seek assistance on this issue
Verified that data passed to ViewBag.data from my controller has ">" symbol.

```
ChartService objMD = new ChartService();
ViewBag.data = objMD.GetAgingInc();
```

I am getting an issue with VIEW:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["table"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Count of Days');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Total');


    @foreach(var item in ViewBag.data)
    {
        @: data.addRow(['@item.Title',@item.Total]);
            }
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: false, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
}
```

Please advise why the value of `@item.Title` is being turned to ">"
when page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@Html.Raw(item.Title)` to prevent html encoding on the View

Comment: What if the title is "About O'Malley"? This will lead to a javascript error.

Comment: @HansKesting Totally agree

Answer (score 1):

Your code `@item.Title` html-encodes the text. Usually (when injecting into HTML) this is what you want. This encoding turns a `>` into a `&gt;` as you saw.

However, you are creating a block of javascript! Here you must use a different encoding: `@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Title)`. This will escape your text correctly for javascript.

Using Html.Raw will cause problems when your Title contains a quote, as that will lead to incorrect javascript.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxhelper.javascriptstringencode.aspx